# new to sqlite3, finally come here after tried thousands ways to solve it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, xcode, sqlite

I'm new to Xcode and trying to learning myself, my problem may be naive but I really need helps.
I'm learning creating an ebook by learning from a finished project with source code.
It works perfectly about recording bookmark through sqlite3.
But when I create a new project with different name and path, built pharse of libsqlite3.dylib correctly and copied almost everything of the code, the else statement is called and crashes when I'm trying to visit bookmark window.

Here's some question I asked myself,

1. did I miss anything, or failed on changing names or paths? answered: no.
2. as the one runs perfectly and the other one with almost same code crashes, what's the most possible mistake? answered: the very few differences from these two project,etc path, name, content in file.

Then I changed the database file name of the good project, and it becomes crashing.
I couldn't believe, because I heard that `sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &dataBase);` will create file if it doesn't exist, why won't it just create a new file with the new name after it was told to access the new file?

Second test I did is manually changing the db file path of the new project to the db file path of the original one. like the path is no more `[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];` but it is @"/Users/~(path of the original one)~/Documents/archive" and omg it works.
But of course I can't leave it like that cause that path means nothing on a real iPhone and it still depends the db file of the original one.

At least I know the path really matters and I seems really missing some thing like db file in my new project.
But the thing is I didn't find any db file in the path of the original project, it seems exist and important, but doesn't show in finder.

I even tried to copy the file to my new path programmaticlly, like calling [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded]; with the new and the old path.
That's all I tried so far.

The strange thing is it somehow record font and color after an unknown attempt, but still crashes on going to bookmark window.

That's all I tried in three days. It may help you answer the question or at least know how I was upset after thousands attempts.
Waiting for help and thank you very much!

const char *createSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BOOKMARK(pos REAL PRIMARY KEY,\fontsize REAL,\bookpath TEXT)";

newly added: As the program automatically issue the crash when the database is not prepared, the error meg, as someone said, is useless. All I need is maybe making `sqlite3_prepare(dataBase, [querySQL UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK` not false..

Comment: Exactly where does it crash, and with what error message?  Did you add your database file to your project?

Comment: Please provide the error message that you get at runtime.

Comment: thanks for reminding!the error msgs are added.

Comment: have you tried setting a breakpoint on the first line of `gotoBookmarks:` method body and then doing the step over to know the exact line of the crash?

Comment: The error message is completely irrelevant because you're triggering the crash yourself with the assertion that will always fail.

Comment: Hi Eimantas, it seems sqlite3_prepare(dataBase, [querySQL UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK is false, that causes the else being called which stops the program.

Comment: Hi, omz, do you know which way can I get error msg without NSAssert(0, @"failed");? cause even it doesn't crash the database is not being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL you're using to create the table in the new DB appears to be messed up. Try removing the \'s

Try this instead:

```
const char *createSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BOOKMARK(pos REAL PRIMARY KEY, fontsize REAL, bookpath TEXT)";
```

Additionally you should take a look at what `sqlite3_prepare` actually returns. The SQLite documentation gives a list of [error codes](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html) to check against. An example of logging the error code:

```
int ret = sqlite3_prepare(dataBase, [querySQL UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil);
if (ret != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Error calling sqlite3_prepare: %d", ret);
}
```

Comment: What a surprised answer. I learned a class which is the running code may not be correct. I shouldn't have assumed the / was not excess. But I never thought the writer changed the code after once running the code. I correctly focused on the uniqueness of the folder. I even correctly focused on the two lines bad code. But I'm just lack of skepticism. My conclusion, To think something else as problem rather than the problem itself. The hardest answer should be the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you print out the value written to errorMsg?  That will at least tell you why you're not creating the database.

NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:errorMsg]);

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me more details? like which method and which line should I insert?

Comment: you have the line:     int ret = sqlite3_exec(dataBase, createSQL, NULL, NULL, &errorMsg);
You're already getting the errorMsg in this line.  Add the NSLog to print it to the console.